# Can I use .NET Newtonsoft JSON package (with or without Linq) to deserialize this oddly formatted JSON response?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I receive this JSON response (but I'm not even sure if this is valid JSON. is it?):

```
"{\"fields\":\"Name,ParentName,Description,StartDate,EndDate,StartMinute,EndMinute\",\"pos\":0,\"start\":0,\"totalRecords\":1001881,\"data\":[[null,\"AAEC 3400 76142\",null,\"2014-05-15T00:00:00\",\"2014-05-15T00:00:00\",840,1050],[null,\"AAEC 3400 76142\",null,\"2014-05-28T00:00:00\",\"2014-05-28T00:00:00\",840,1050],[null,\"ACCT 5400 25030\",null,\"2014-01-08T00:00:00\",\"2014-01-08T00:00:00\",1215,1290],[null,\"ACCT 5400 25030\",null,\"2014-02-19T00:00:00\",\"2014-02-19T00:00:00\",1215,1290]]}"
```

Is it possible to deserialize this response and access particular values using Newtonsoft JSON package, with or without the LINQ namespace? Can I access specific values from the "data" key?

Currently, my approach is to manipulate this JSON response into regular JSON, so instead of just having a "fields" key and a "data" key followed by lists of values, I end up deserializing normal JSON key/value pairs (like "Name":"null", "ParentName":"AAEC 3400 76142\", . . . ). Then I can access each object in the list's values by key.

But is it possible to access specific values keeping the response the way it came, without parsing/manipulating it, using Newtonsoft JSON package with/without methods in LINQ namespace?

This is how I'm deserializing the json string that I parse/manipulated manually into normal JSON:

```
var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(json);
```

Then I can access values by key off of specific objects in the response by index:

```
String name = myList[0].Name;
```

But can I access the value of myList[0].Name without reformatting the JSON response into typical key:value pairs? Does Newtonsoft provide a way to access the value I want from the response the way it came?

Comment: it looks like a valid json to me other than that double quotes are escaped.

Comment: Are you sure that's how the data came across, and not just how it's being displayed to you by Visual Studio? Also, you should show how you're currently deserializing it and how you'd rather do it.

Comment: @mason yes I am sure this is how the data came across, as I have to remove the backslashes when manipulating this into normal valid json.

Comment: @JonathanVance Who sent you the JSON? Where's your code?

Comment: @mason the JSON is a response from a web service call; i'm trying to be as clear as I can without sharing sensitive info

Comment: @JonathanVance Who's web service is it? Your own? Then fix it to send proper JSON. If it's someone else's, then have them fix the output. Otherwise, you will continue to have to manipulate the JSON into the proper form. I don't know of any JSON library that would manipulate the JSON into the proper format for you, and I don't think we would want that anyways. Whoever is generating the JSON should run it through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is straightforward and simple to deserialize a JSON response formatted in this way using the Newtonsoft JSON package with LINQ namespace. You don't have to manipulate the response string by hand. Set the JSON response string to a string object named "response", use JObject.Parse() to create a dynamic object "jobject", then you can access the "data" JSON key and set it to a JArray object. Then you can loop through each JToken in "jArray". Finally, get the values by their index in the JArray:

```
dynamic jobject = JObject.Parse(response);
JArray jArray = jobject.data;

foreach (JToken appointment in jArray)
           { 
               parentName = appointment[1];
               startMinute = appointment[5];
               . . .
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that JSON has been double-serialized.  I.e. some class was serialized as a JSON string, then that string was serialized as JSON *again*, causing [JSON control characters](http://json.org/) including `{`,`}` and `"` characters to be escaped.

This is almost certainly a bug on the server side, you should try to get it fixed there.  But if you *cannot* (for political reasons, say), you can check for this and work around it on the client side:

```
        var token = JToken.Parse(json);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
            token = JToken.Parse((string)token);
        var myList = token.ToObject<List<MyClass>>();
```

Update: your root JSON container is an object, not an array, so `ToObject<List<MyClass>>` won't work.  The unwrapped JSON looks like:

> ```
> {
>   "fields": "Name,ParentName,Description,StartDate,EndDate,StartMinute,EndMinute",
>   "pos": 0,
>   "start": 0,
>   "totalRecords": 1001881,
>   "data": [
>     [
>       null,
>       "AAEC 3400 76142",
>       null,
>       "2014-05-15T00:00:00",
>       "2014-05-15T00:00:00",
>       840,
>       1050
>     ],
>     // More of the same
>   ]
> }
> ```

If you wanted to reformat that into a more traditional array of JSON objects, you could restructure your root `JToken` like so:

```
        var token = JToken.Parse(json);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
            token = JToken.Parse((string)token);

        var fields = (string)token.SelectToken("fields");
        var fieldList = fields.Split(',');
        var root = new JArray();
        root.Add(token.SelectTokens("data[*]").OfType<JArray>().Select(a => new JObject(a.Zip(fieldList, (t, s) => new JProperty(s, t)))));
        Debug.WriteLine(root);
```

With the result:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "Name": null,
>     "ParentName": "AAEC 3400 76142",
>     "Description": null,
>     "StartDate": "2014-05-15T00:00:00",
>     "EndDate": "2014-05-15T00:00:00",
>     "StartMinute": 840,
>     "EndMinute": 1050
>   },
>   // More of the same
> ]
> ```